# Real solution to simple hyperbolic function equation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I have the following question:

"Under what condition does the following equation have a real solution?
$$ b x=2\sinh(a x), $$
where $a$ and $b$ are given real constants."

I can simply think of a solution by intersecting the line $y_{1}=bx$ with the curve of $y_{2}=2\sinh(ax)$. For them to intersect, the slope of the line ($b$) has to be larger than the slope of the tangent of $y_{2}$ at $x=0$, which gives the condition: $b\geq 2a$. Is this correct? And would you say this is the answer the question is looking for?

The question is still puzzling to me, as it asks for the condition of a *real* solution (not just a 'solution'). Any ideas or suggestions about this? How different would things be for a complex solution? Or is the question just badly phrased?

Comment: $x=0$ is always a solution, the existence of other solutions depends on whether or not $b>2a$.  $b=2a$ will not give more solutions.  Then it should all be good.

Comment: @Simply Thanks. But why does the question have the word 'real' in front of 'solution'?